# Typeorm How Can I get Min field with Where clause?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I use Typeorm and nestjs in my project.
I have Schema:

```
export class GroupEntity implements IGroup {
  // Attributes
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'string' })
  public id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'string', nullable: false })
  public userId: string;

  @Column({ type: 'int2' })
  public syncStatus: number;
}
```

I want to get min sync status by userId where syncStatus is not null

exampleData:

```
[{
  id: "1",
  userId: "101",
  syncStatus: 2
}, {
  id: "2",
  userId: "101",
  syncStatus: 3
}, {
  id: "2",
  userId: "105",
  syncStatus: -5
}, {
  id: "2",
  userId: "101",
  syncStatus: null
}]
```

expected result

```
2
or row with value 2
```

Big thx!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use `MIN`, Here's how:

```
return this.groupRepository.createQueryBuilder('group')
.select("MIN(group.syncStatus)",'syncStatus')
.addSelect(['group.id','group.userId'])
.where('group.userId = :user", {
    user,
  })
.andWhere('group.syncStatus is not null')
.getRawOne();
```